# When Allah gives you hardship can you ask Allah for help?

Tags: practical-islam

If your being tested with hardship and your being not being ungrateful can you do a dua to get rid of the hardship is that complaining or being ungrateful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Allah tests you with hardship, it's a calling from him.
How else will you get over a struggle if you don't ask the almighty for help?
Allah doesn't want you to be among the disbelievers so by testing you, it will make you come back to Him and pray to Him to ease your struggle.

So praying because of a specific hardship you're facing is not being ungrateful. Just know that being tested is something you should not be ungrateful for, regardless of the struggle because it holds a lot of reward for you.

> "Do the people think that they will be left to say, “We believe” and they will not be tried? But We have certainly tried those before them, and Allah will surely make evident those who are truthful, and He will surely make evident those who are false." 
> **-Qur’an 29:2-3**

Being tested by Allah has its virtues such as:

**1. Allah tests us to purify us and wash away our sins.**
The Prophet (saw) said:

> “No calamity befalls a Muslim but that Allah expiates some of his sins
> because of it, even if it were the prick of a thorn.” 
> **-Bukhari, Muslim**

**2. Tests are given to us to strengthen our faith.**

The Prophet (saw) said:

> “The people who face the most difficult tests are the prophets, then
> the righteous, then those following them in degree. A person is tried
> according to his religion. So if there is firmness in his religion,
> then the trial is increased, and if there is a weakness, then it is
> lightened. Verily a trial remains with a servant until he walks the
> earth having no sin left upon him.” 
>  **-Bukhari**

**3. Allah tests a person He loves** 
The Prophet (saw) said:

> “Whenever Allah wills good for a person, He subjects them to
> adversity”. 
>  **-Bukhari**

Because if the servant reacts with patience and contentment with Allah’s decree, it brings them closer to Allah. And “Allah loves the Patient” (Qur’an 3:146).

These are just a few benefits of being tested, you most certainly can make dua to Allah to make it easier because that's what Allah intends for you to do. He's trying to bring you back to Him so you can worship Him and be guided on the straight path.

Comment: Can you ask people for help?

Comment: @KavalySidibey Yes, but you shouldn't ignore going back to Allah.